# Передача данных с одной страницы на другую javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Как передать 3начение points и3 одной страницы на другую страницу и вывести ?

```
var arrLostCards = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
points = arrLostCards.length / 2 * 42;
document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points;
<div id="textContentAgain" >Очки: <span id="points"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая страница

```
   function showScore() {
    window.open('finish.html?&'+points);
    }
```

Вторая страница с выводом

```
<script>
function scoreGame() {
    var score = decodeURIComponent(location.search.substr(1)).split('&');
    score.splice(0, 1);
    var result = score[0];
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

<body onload="scoreGame();">      <!--3апуск функции при полной прогру3ке страницы-->
<div id="textContentEnd" ><p>Ваш счет:<span id="result"></span></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете это сделать, если только для одного сайта (доменного имени) с помощью хранилища:

```
var arrLostCards = [];
if (!localStorage.getItem("arrLostCards")) {
    arrLostCards = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    localStorage.setItem("arrLostCards", JSON.stringify(arrLostCards))
} else arrLostCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arrLostCards"));
```

Comment: Ну или через базу данных....

Comment: Ради одного параметра делать бд ?? А методом передачи GET и POST?

Comment: А методы POST и GET - это запросы к серверу. Как раз этот случай сложнее, требует одновременно и хранилища (куки) и бэкенда.

Comment: первая страницы index1

`var points=0;
 if (!localStorage.getItem("points")) {
 var arrLostCards = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
 points = arrLostCards.length / 2 * 42;
 localStorage.setItem("points ", JSON.stringify(points )) 
} else points = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("points"));`
index2 А как выводить?

document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points;
 <div <span id="points"></span></div>

Answer (score 0):

Ну както так

```
var arrLostCards = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
points = arrLostCards.length / 2 * 42;
document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points;
<div id="textContentAgain" >Очки: <span id="points"></span></div>
var nw = window.open("адрес");
nw.ps = points;//в новом окне будет переменная ps  со значением points
```

Comment: я уже написал как я сделал выше) Но все равно спасибо(